# Python dash: how to combine user input with other text on same line

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I'm trying to combine in the same row some text with user-defined text. I would like to keep the "some text" out of the callback definition for organization. How can I combine some strings of text with user-defined input strings? An example below, note how `html.Div()` and `html.P()` returns text in 2 different lines

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='user-input', type='text', placeholder='Enter a string...'),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div([
        html.P("Here's an additional paragraph for context:"), ## line 1
        html.Div(id='output-text') ## line 2
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('output-text', 'children'),
    [Input('user-input', 'value')]
)
def update_text(input_value):
    return f'This is the text: {input_value}'

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Returns:
[image]

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain how exactly it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can use `dash.html.Span` components to avoid automatically introduced linebreaks between *static* and [*callback-triggered*] *dynamic* app content

Exactly like in standard HTML, Dash HTML Span components are rendered in a Dash app webpage as [**inline-level elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).

E.g.,:

```py
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Input(
            id="user-input", type="text", placeholder="Enter a string..."
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Span(
                    "Here's an additional paragraph for context: "
                ),                            ## line 1
                html.Span(id="output-text"),  ## line 2
            ]
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("output-text", "children"), [Input("user-input", "value")]
)
def update_text(input_value):
    return f"This is the text: {input_value}"

app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=True)
```

produces:

[image: GIF screen recording showing dash app with html.span components avoiding linebreaks]